Issues in conversion of a specific string to dictionary
I'd like to convert a string into dict. The input string is taken from the database.
Below is the log.before (this is the given string from the databse)given.
{'id': '25c16650-070c-4e17-8996-f8d79d1747d7', 'tariff': OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('title', 'dTtvdvemDLYDHZiPNfaDwgAsTopnQBvYiHVPJvlREQaqLtlJFkQVFKZhpmWWphaxedqzWZBcpXxglKZvgpzPzPVEkSnJfEHnVfHy'), ('price', '0.00'), ('label', '(None) dTtvdvemDLYDHZiPNfaDwgAsTopnQBvYiHVPJvlREQaqLtlJFkQVFKZhpmWWphaxedqzWZBcpXxglKZvgpzPzPVEkSnJfEHnVfHy')]), 'title': 'Test Product', 'price': None, 'establishment': 0.0, 'billing_period': 'M', 'additional_points': [], 'speed_unit': 'Gb', 'service_type': 'P', 'type': 'S', 'show_with_vat': True, 'price_with_vat': 0, 'establishment_with_vat': 0, 'has_express_delivery': False, 'conversion_reporting_configs': [], 'index': 1, 'speed_up': 'None', 'speed_down': 'None'}

In order to convert this string to dict, I've written like this.
try:
   before = ast.literal_eval(log.before) if log.before else {}
except Exception as e:
   print(e)

And there's an error like this.
malformed node or string: <ast.Call object at 0x7fb3b60d94f0>

I think the problem is with the OrderedDict in the string given.
Just for the record, below is the full code snippet.

import csv
import ast
# import json
# import re
from collections import OrderedDict
from io import StringIO

from core.celery import app as celery_app
from django.utils.timezone import now, timedelta
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings

from intern.apps.geo.models import GeoLog, GeoUpload, GeoUploadProcess
from intern.apps.geo.processors import GeoFileProcessor

@celery_app.task
def generate_geo_manager_report(start_date=None, end_date=None):

    if start_date is None and end_date is None:
        end_date = now()
        start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=7)

    logs = GeoLog.objects.filter(when__range=[start_date, end_date])

    if not logs.exists():
        print("No logs found, exiting task.")
        return
    
    stats = {model: {action: 0 for action in GeoLog.Action.values} for model in GeoLog.ModelType.values}

    csv_files = {model: [] for model in GeoLog.ModelType.values}

    for log in logs:
        if log.model_type is None:
            print(f"Skipping log due to None model_type: {log}")
            continue
        print("GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG")
    
        stats[log.model_type][log.action] += 1

        print(f"Raw before: {log.before}")
        print(f"Raw after: {log.after}")

        try:
            before = ast.literal_eval(log.before) if log.before else {}
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        try:
            after = ast.literal_eval(log.after) if log.after else {}
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        print(f"Serialized after: {before}")
        print(f"Serialized after: {after}")

        if log.action == 'update':
            changes = {
                key: (before[key], after[key]) if before.get(key) != after.get(key) else before[key]
                for key in set(before) | set(after)
            }
        else:
            changes = {**before, **after}

        # print(f"Serialized before: {before}")
        # print(f"Serialized after: {after}")

        csv_files[log.model_type].append({
            'changes': changes,
            'action': log.action,
            'when': log.when,
            'employee': log.employee.username if log.employee else 'System'
        })
        print("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")
        print(f"Serialized csv_flies: {type(csv_files)}")

    attachments = []
    for model, rows in csv_files.items():
        if rows:
            output = StringIO()
            writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=rows[0].keys())
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(rows)
            attachments.append((f"{model}.csv", output.getvalue()))

    subject = settings.GEO_MANAGER_REPORT_SUBJECT.format(
        start_date=start_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
        end_date=end_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
    )
    body = (
        f"Geo Manager Report for period {start_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} to {end_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}\n\n"
        + "\n".join(
            f"{sum(stats[model].values())} changes in {model} ({', '.join(f'{count} {action}' for action, count in actions.items() if count > 0)})"
            for model, actions in stats.items()
        )
    )
    print("Sending email...")
    email = EmailMessage(subject, body, to=settings.GEO_MANAGER_REPORT_RECIPIENTS)
    for filename, content in attachments:
        email.attach(filename, content, 'text/csv')
    email.send()


trying to evluate your dictionary gives an error NameError: name 'OrderedDict' is not defined. Please post a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Yeah. You'll need to eval this as code, and make sure you've imported all the necessary classes like OrderedDict first. This is a terrible idea. Why do you have this string in the database in the first place?

@Cincinnatus That is a [mre], that is exactly the problem OP will need to solve…
